# What URL should Munin be available at after default install?

Tags: server, apache2, monitoring, munin

I have installed Munin according to the [basic server instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/munin.html) (I am planning on using it to monitor my own machine, not a remote machine). I installed the `apache2` and `munin` packages (which included the `munin-node` and `munin-plugins-extra` packages).

`/etc/munin/munin.conf` already includes:

```
[localhost.localdomain]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes
```

`/etc/munin/munin-node.conf` already includes:

```
allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
allow ^::1$
```

I have called `sudo service munin-node restart` and rebooted my machine and munin is still not visible at `http://localhost/munin` (`http://localhost` shows the default Apache 2 on Ubuntu page as expected).

What URL should Munin be visible on? (And if the URL is correct, what am I missing?)

Answer (score 0):

It should be running on port 10000 by default, IIRC:

```
http://localhost:10000
```

And I think `munin` uses its own web server, not the system's webserver.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the Munin webpage is reachable via

http://localhost/munin/

please check if there is a /var/www/munin/ directory with html files on the Munin Server.